# How to make a timespan column based on a time stamp column?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, difftime

I have a datatable with timestamps in column 1 and events in column 2. The timestamps have the format `Y-m-d H:M:OS3` (e.g. `"2019-09-26 07:29:22,778"`).

I would like to add a new column with time-span values of the difference between timestamp 2 to timestamp 1, then 3 to 1 etc. E.g.:

```
timestamp                  event           diff in sec
2019-09-26 07:29:22,778    X                   
2019-09-26 07:29:23,918    Y               1.140
2019-09-26 07:29:25,118    Z               2.340
.
.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base`:

```r
dt1$timediff <- cumsum(c(0, difftime(tail(dt1$timestamp,-1), head(dt1$timestamp,-1))))
```

or using `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

dt1[ , timediff := cumsum(c(0, diff(as.numeric(timestamp))))][]
#>                  timestamp event timediff
#> 1: 2019-09-26 07:29:22.778     X     0.00
#> 2: 2019-09-26 07:29:23.917     Y     1.14
#> 3: 2019-09-26 07:29:25.118     Z     2.34
```

Another `dplyr` solution base off of *akrun's* answer:

```r
library(dplyr)
dt1 %>%
  mutate(difftime = difftime(timestamp, timestamp[1], unit = 'sec'))
```

***Data:***
*N.B*: I am using `data.table` to read the data.

```r
fread(text="date time  event
 2019-09-26 07:29:22.778    X                   
 2019-09-26 07:29:23.918    Y               
 2019-09-26 07:29:25.118    Z") -> dt1

dt1$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(paste(dt1$date, dt1$time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")

dt1 <- dt1[,4:3]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `difftime`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   mutate(timestamp = ymd_hms(timestamp),
          diffinsec = cumsum(as.numeric(difftime(timestamp, 
       lag(timestamp, default = timestamp[1]), unit = 'sec'))))
```

Comment: How do I wrap it with as.numeric? In my hands, it results in integer values for the "diff in sec" column, however I would like to get the milliseconds as well (e.g. 2,340 sec).

Comment: No, they are character columns, only the new one "diffinsec" is numeric. How would you read in the data file while keeping the timestamp format intact and? Alternatively, how would you convert columns 1 and 2 to numeric columns?

Comment: @W.H.G.  Not clear though.  If you want to convert columns 1 to 2 to numeric `df1 %>% mutate_at(1:2, as.numeric) %>%`

Comment: Fine, thanks. But how do I get to values in "diff in sec" that include milliseconds (e.g.: 2,340 sec)?

Comment: Here, we used the `unit` as `sec` and if you check `?difftime`, the units option includes only `c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours",
                   "days", "weeks")` so you may have to convert it to milliseconds by doing some arithmetic afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution with `dplyr`. I assumed that you want the time difference from the first event. Otherwise @akrun's answer with `lag()` is the correct one.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(start = min(timestamp)) %>% 
  mutate(diff = timestamp - start)
#>             timestamp             event               start      diff
#> 1 2019-09-26 07:29:22                 X 2019-09-26 07:29:22 0.00 secs
#> 2 2019-09-26 07:29:23                 Y 2019-09-26 07:29:22 1.14 secs
#> 3 2019-09-26 07:29:25                 Z 2019-09-26 07:29:22 2.34 secs
```

### data

```
df <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1569479362.778, 1569479363.918, 
                                                 1569479365.118), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
                         event = c("X", "Y", "Z")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                  -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I still don't succeed to get to the right format, I would like to ask you how you would deal with an input text file that looks exactly like this:                  
2019-09-26 17:54:24,406 [218] INFO  - [1] - Event X
2019-09-26 17:54:24,431 [207] INFO  - [1] - Event Y
2019-09-26 17:54:24,438 [218] INFO  - [1] - Event Z

Comment: I think you should ask a new question where you make your requirements a bit clearer. I don't know what you are getting at and your original problem seems to be solved.